# The named parameter 'XXX' is required, but there's no corresponding argument

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutterflow

i am FlutterFlow to create my own CustomWidget, which is basically a QR Code Generator "qr_flutter".

**Somehow i always get following errors**:

- The named parameter 'PARAMETER' is required, but there's no
  corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument.
- The argument type 'QrImage' can't be assigned to the parameter type
  'Widget?'.
- 1 positional argument expected by 'QrImage.new', but 0 found. Try
  adding the missing argument.
- Expected a class member. Try placing this code inside a class member.

```
// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/backend/backend.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:qr_flutter/qr_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(QrCodeGenerator());

class QrCodeGenerator extends StatefulWidget {
  const QrCodeGenerator({
    Key? key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    required this.qrData,
    required this.qrVersion,
    required this.qrSize,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final String qrData;
  final int qrVersion;
  final double qrSize;

  @override
  _QrCodeGeneratorState createState() => _QrCodeGeneratorState();
}

class _QrCodeGeneratorState extends State<QrCodeGenerator> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      child: QrImage(
      data: qrData,
      version: qrVersion ?? QrVersions.auto,
      size: qrSize,
      )
    );
  };
}
```

[These are my Widget Settings:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG59B.png)

Any help or related link/post would be appreciated to bring me ahead.

Actually i tried many things to solve it e.g. using fixed values and not parameters, but there is somewhere else something wrong which i dont get.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you wanna display the QR code dynamically based on the data passed as params, You are using the `QrImage` widget in your code instead of that you should try `QrImageView` from the same library, it might resolve your issue. For reference, you can check the below-mentioned code snippet of the build method you can try changing the widget in your code.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      child: QrImageView(
        data: widget.qrData,
        size: widget.qrSize,
        version: widget.qrVersion ?? QrVersions.auto,
      ),
    );
  }
```